# Delete old unused Prestashop customers using SQL

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

Due to problems in the database I need to delete old customers from Prestashop 1.6 who:

- Registered before January 1, 2014
- Haven't log in since January 1, 2014
- Haven't made a purchase since January 1, 2014

But since I don't know well the Prestashop database I have these questions:

- Seems log in data is only stored in ps_connections and it get's deleted. Does ps_customer.date_upd can help me?
- What extra data do I have to delete a customer? I suppose ps_address. Any other?

Comment: you want to do it by direct sql querie(s), I got it, but just notice: you can check `Customer` model class. $customer->date_add, getLastConnections(), getStats(), **delete()** etc. Also, if customer haven't logged since 1.1.2014 then he can't purchase anything... :) if we talk about registered users and completed orders

Comment: you should take a look in pscleaner module

Answer (score 0):

Here's a request that prints all the log information about all users in the base.

```
SELECT c.date_add as date, u.email as email, u.firstname as firstname, u.lastname as lastname, u.id_customer as id FROM ps_guest g, ps_connections c, ps_customer u
WHERE c.id_guest = g.id_guest AND
g.id_customer = u.id_customer
GROUP BY c.date_add
ORDER BY `date`  DESC
```

**The registering date** equals to the smallest date: (I changed the MIN(c.date_add and the GROUP BY)

```
SELECT MIN(c.date_add) as date, u.email as email, u.firstname as firstname, u.lastname as lastname, u.id_customer as id FROM ps_guest g, ps_connections c, ps_customer u
WHERE c.id_guest = g.id_guest AND
g.id_customer = u.id_customer
GROUP BY u.id_customer
```

**The last login date** equals to the bigger date : (I changed the MAX(c.date_add) and the GROUP BY)

```
SELECT MAX(c.date_add) as date, u.email as email, u.firstname as firstname, u.lastname as lastname, u.id_customer as id FROM ps_guest g, ps_connections c, ps_customer u
WHERE c.id_guest = g.id_guest AND
g.id_customer = u.id_customer
GROUP BY u.id_customer
```

About your log question, you can notice the ps_guest and ps_connection has stored values. And I confirm that **ps_customer.date_upd it useless about the logging** ^^

About deleting a customer, I searched all occurences of id_customer in the base without any extra-installed-modules. Here the result:

```
ps_customer_message
ps_customer_message 
ps_order_slip   
ps_cart 
ps_specific_price   
ps_customer_group   
ps_address  
ps_customer_thread  
ps_customer_thread  
ps_order_return 
ps_orders   
ps_message  
ps_guest    
ps_cart_rule    
ps_customer
```

Those tables contains information about a "id_customer". If you want to erase completely a user just run:

```
DELETE FROM <your table> WHERE id_customer = <your customer's id>
```